# How to access internet from android emulator?

Tags: android

I have used below steps for setup the my emulator

1.`C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\tools>adb shell`

2. `# sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db`
3. `sqlite> INSERT INTO system VALUES(99,’http_proxy', '10.10.8.1:8080');`

after that i closed `adb shell command prompt` and my emulator. and then opened my emulator but webbrowser is not opening any page(`web page not available messaage`) .

Please any one tell me the solution for this problem.
is any other way to connect net in android emulator?

Regards,
Jeyavel N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I couldn't force my emulator to use proxy. I tried to run the emulator with -http-proxy but it didn't work. I believe it's an equivalent for what you did with sql lite. If you need internet just on browser, you could try to set APN in your emulator (Home > Menu > Settings > Wireless Controls > Mobile Networks > Access Point Names) there you can set your proxy. It worked for me, but it wasn't what I was looking for.

Well, to be honest I'm afraid that the only option is to redirect traffic on your local system. I didn't try this, but maybe such application can do this:[TunnelEx](http://tunnelex.software.informer.com/1.2/) 
I hope that works.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a proxy, you can launch the emulator from the command line like this:

```
emulator -http-proxy <<your proxy here>> -avd <<emulator-name>>
```

Comment: This is shaky at best. I've had a lot of problems with this in 1.5 and 1.6, and I know others have as well. It would be really nice if Google could get the network stack of the emulator to be a little more robust.